# How do I sort the list of data in reverse date order?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Sample XML:

```xml
<AssignmentHistory>
    <PublicTalkInfo>
        <PublicTalkNumber>21</PublicTalkNumber>
        <PublicTalkSpeaker>Name3</PublicTalkSpeaker>
        <PublicTalkCongregation>Place3</PublicTalkCongregation>
    </PublicTalkInfo>
    <PublicTalkInfo>
        <MeetingDate>2023-10-15</MeetingDate>
        <PublicTalkNumber>21</PublicTalkNumber>
        <PublicTalkSpeaker>Name</PublicTalkSpeaker>
        <PublicTalkCongregation>Place</PublicTalkCongregation>
    </PublicTalkInfo>
    <PublicTalkInfo>
        <MeetingDate>2023-11-15</MeetingDate>
        <PublicTalkNumber>21</PublicTalkNumber>
        <PublicTalkSpeaker>Name2 </PublicTalkSpeaker>
        <PublicTalkCongregation>Place</PublicTalkCongregation>
    </PublicTalkInfo>
</AssignmentHistory>
```

I cut it down for simplification.

```
public string[] GetHistoryForTalkOutline(string historyDatabase, int talknumber)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(historyDatabase);
        var ptInfo = doc
                        .Descendants("PublicTalkInfo")
                        .Where(p => p.Element("PublicTalkNumber").Value == talknumber.ToString()).ToList();
        SimpleLog.Log(ptInfo.Count().ToString());
           foreach (var pt in ptInfo)
           {
               var date = pt.Element("MeetingDate");
               var speaker = pt.Element("PublicTalkSpeaker");
               var cong = pt.Element("PublicTalkCongregation");

               if (date != null && speaker != null && cong != null)
               {
                   DateTime objectdate = DateTime.Parse(date.Value);
                   string histitem = objectdate.ToString("d") + ", ";
                   histitem += speaker.Value + " (";
                   histitem += cong.Value + ")";
                   list.Add(histitem);
               }

           }

        return list.ToArray();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SimpleLog.Log(ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am sure the code can be simplified. But how can I build my final list of strings with the content in descending date order? Note that some entries do not have the fields in.

Comment: Please ensure you give valid XML. The XML here doesn't have a root element and the closing tags don't all match so wouldn't even be able to be parsed

Comment: @DavidG I improved it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing all the values in a list of strings, you can instead keep them in a format that retains the date value. For example, using a [tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples):

```
List<(DateTime Date, string Value)> list = new List<(DateTime, string)>();
```

Later when you add to the list, do this:

```
list.Add((objectdate, histitem));
```

And to return the values in the order you need, use some simple Linq:

```
return list
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I like this approach because it limits to work involved to just the data of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something along these lines

```cs
using System.Xml.Linq;

....
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        
        var emptyDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        var sortedElements = doc.Root.Elements("PublicTalkInfo")
            .OrderByDescending(e => e.Element("MeetingDate") != null 
                ? (DateTime)e.Element("MeetingDate") 
                : emptyDate)
            .ToList();
```

If you want elements without a meeting date to show up at the top of the list, you can replace `DateTime.MinValue` -> `DateTime.MaxValue`

Comment: This would throw an exception when the `MeetingDate` element is missing

Comment: You are right, corrected it in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, something like this should help::

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
XElement root = XElement.Load("file.xml");
var orderedtabs = root.Elements("PublicTalkInfo")
                    .OrderBy(xtab => (DateTime?)xtab.Element("MeetingDate"))
                    .ToArray();
root.RemoveAll();
foreach(XElement tab in orderedtabs)
    root.Add(tab);
root.Save("file-sorted.xml");
```